# Intercalar valores de un array

Tags: php, array, codeigniter

Tengo la siguiente consulta: estoy trabajando con un formulario que me genera un array del tipo,

```
$array=array(
    "[0]" => "Pregunta 1",
    "[1]" => "Respuesta 1",
    "[2]" => "Pregunta 2",
    "[3]" => "Respuesta 2",
    "[4]" => "Pregunta 3",
    "[5]" => "Respuesta 3"
    );
```

El número de elementos del array, difiere en función del número de respuestas que se contestan en el formulario, con lo que puede haber 6 o 26.
A la hora de presentar los datos, necesitaría poder dividir el array en dos: uno con las respuestas y otro con las preguntas, teniendo en cuenta que el array original siempre intercala pregunta con respuesta. En resumen, necesito convertir el array original en algo similar a:

```
$array=array(
"Pregunta 1" => "Respuesta 1",
"Pregunta 2" => "Respuesta 2",
"Pregunta 3" => "Respuesta 3"
);
```

Para después podré recorrer bien el array y presentar los datos como corresponde.

¿Alguna idea de por donde tirar?
Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Te has saltado deliberadamente el índice **"[5]"** en tu array? Es decir, ¿se puede dar este caso o siempre serán números consecutivos?

Comment: Buenos días y gracias por el interés. Ha sido una errata, ya lo he corregido.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(
    "[0]" => "Pregunta 1",
    "[1]" => "Respuesta 1",
    "[2]" => "Pregunta 2",
    "[3]" => "Respuesta 2",
    "[4]" => "Pregunta 3",
    "[5]" => "Respuesta 3"
);

$nuevo_array = array();
$array_preguntas = array();
$array_respuestas = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        array_push($array_preguntas, $array["[$i]"]);
    }
    else {
        array_push($array_respuestas, $array["[$i]"]);
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_preguntas); $i++) {
    $nuevo_array[$array_preguntas[$i]] = $array_respuestas[$i]; 
}

var_dump ($nuevo_array);
```

Quizás mi solución sea un poco rudimentaria y pueda hacerse algo similar usando alguna de las funciones que nos facilita **PHP** para el manejo de `arrays`, pero podría valerte.

Lo que hago es dividir tu `array` en 2, uno de **preguntas** y otro de **respuestas**. Para ello, me aprovecho de que las **preguntas** tienen un índice par y las **respuestas** uno impar para saber en la iteración si estoy tratando con una **pregunta** o una **respuesta**. Una vez identificado, almaceno el dato en su `array` correspondiente.

Por último, hago un segundo bucle para ir extrayendo del `array` de **preguntas** y del de **respuestas** sus datos correspondientes (`$array_preguntas[0]` es la pregunta de `$array_respuestas[0]` y así sucesivamente) para ir formando un nuevo array ya ordenado acorde a tus necesidades.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. He encontrado otra solución que adjunto aquí por si a alguien le es de utilidad:

Answer (score 0):

Una solución que he encontrado en otro sitio al problema que planteaba:

```
$array=array(
    "[0]" => "Pregunta 1",
    "[1]" => "Respuesta 1",
    "[2]" => "Pregunta 2",
    "[3]" => "Respuesta 2",
    "[4]" => "Pregunta 3",
    "[5]" => "Respuesta 3"
    );

$previousElement = null;
$idx = 1;
            foreach ($array as $lastIdx => $questionAnswer) {
                $idx++;
                //check if key is even, otherwise it's odd
                if ($idx % 2 === 0) {
                    $array[$questionAnswer] = $questionAnswer;
                } else {
                    $array[$previousElement] = $questionAnswer;
                }
                //saving element so I can "remember" it in next loop
                $previousElement = $questionAnswer;
                unset($array[$lastIdx]);
            }

            print_r($array);
```